# Objective C: Keep the Hidden Button Shown After App Termination

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, nsdata

I created 2 button in my app, "Download" button and "View" button. The "View" is initially hidden while the "Download" is not.

What I want to happen is, after the download the "View" button will show and "Download" button will be hidden permanently even when the user re-open the app after termination.

What I did is like this:

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
     downloadBtn.hidden = YES;
     viewBtn.hidden = NO;
}
```

but this code I know is not what I needed because it refreshes the app to it's initial values when i re-open it.
Is there a way to do what I wanted?

Answer (score 2):

You have to save the fact that the download has finished, for example by using NSUserDefaults

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setBool: YES forKey: DOWNLOAD_FINISHED_KEY];
[defaults synchronize];
```

The next time the app is launched, you have to read this value from user defaults to determine which button should be shown.

Comment: What identifier is DOWNLOAD_FINISHED_KEY? Should I put it in the appDelegate.m?

Comment: This is actually just a string you define yourself, fx #define DOWNLOAD_FINISHED_KEY  @"DownloadFinishedKey"

Answer (score 0):

You can store data like that in [NSUserDefaults](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class).

Setting the value(on download finished):

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool: YES forKey: @"downloadFinished"];
```

Retrieving it:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"downloadFinished"];
```